# How can I pre-warm a Python azure function or set up pre-warmed instances?

Tags: python, azure, serverless

We have Python Azure httpTrigger functions that have a cold start problem when we scale out. The response time spikes to 10-40s after creating a new instance for scale out. I found 2 possible solutions for this:

- use a [warmupTrigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-warmup?tabs=isolated-process%2Cnodejs-v4&pivots=programming-language-python)
- use a [pre-warmed instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-premium-plan?tabs=azurecli#prewarmed-instances)

It looks like prewarmed instances can be set with something like `preWarmedInstanceCount=n` but I'm not sure if this is applicable for the Premium P3V3 plan we're on. And can I just set that in the function app environment settings, or have to do it via CLI like in the docs?

On the warmupTrigger, I added it as another function within the function app, but it's not firing.

Is there some other option for having scale-out instances wait to take requests until the function code is fully loaded and ready?

Comment: Are you on the Elastic Premium (EP1,EP2,EP3) tier or Premium App service tier? The warmed-up instance is valid for Elastic premium which basically enables warmed instances ready for incoming traffic. This setting can be done upfront manually on the portal for that particular function app or via Powershell, python or CLI scripts(as described in your link). Also, the scaling (up and down) will be taken care of automatically.

Comment: It is P3V3, so I guess not elastic. Will the warmupTrigger not work on non-elastic premium? I don't even see any elastic options under the ASP pricing plan settings page.

Comment: So does that mean we're on a dedicated plan and not premium? Even though the "premium" instances/pricing plans like P3V3 are available?

Comment: I found out we're on the dedicated plan and not the elastic premium. It's very confusing because the "premium" P3V3 instances are actually on the dedicated plan, and the elastic premium plan is different with EP VMs. My understanding is there is no way to avoid a cold-start on the dedicated plan, and warmupTrigger or prewarmedinstances only work on the elastic premium plan, not the dedicated or other plans.

Answer (score 1):

P3V3 is the premium tier of app service. You are just running function on that app service. EP1/2/3 are premium versions of azure functions which have in built elasticity.

I you look at this documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/manage-automatic-scaling?tabs=azure-portal), it talks of a preview automatic scaling functionality and it says that you set the prewarmed instances but only via CLI and not by the portal.
So you can't set this through any Function configuration...yet.

Comment: My understanding is the elastic plan has a default prewarmedinstancecount of 1. And you can only use warmupTrigger on the EP instances, but they don't mention that anywhere in the docs.

Comment: Actually it is mentioned here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-premium-plan?tabs=azurecli#prewarmed-instances. When the docs talks of functions premium plan, they are referring to EP1/2/3. If they had to refer to P1/2/3 it would be an app service premium plan. I think the confusion arises because we can still run a function on an app service plan. And you are right that Elastic plan has 1 prewarmed instance by default. If you are sticking to P3V3, you can check my answer for enabling prewarmed instances. Else switch to EP1/2/3 if you can.

Comment: Thanks, yes they mention the warmupTrigger there but it's not clear in the warmupTrigger docs that it only works for a elastic premium plan. Also I find the terminology "elastic premium" "premium" and "app service premium" all very confusing. It should just be "elastic" "dedicated" "consumption" or something more clear where every plan doesn't have the word "premium" in it. Otherwise when people say "premium" it's unclear which plan it is.